# Mock a constructor and return a mocked object instead of real object with mockk

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mocking, mockk

I have a challenge with a class which I want to test but inside the class other objects will be created.

This simple example shows the issue.

```
class A {
    val b: B
    init() {
      b = B()
    }
}
```

It's just an example and I know that dependency injection would help. But in real life it's a very complex class which can not be changed easily.

My idea was to use `mockkConstructor`. But it does not the trick.

```
fun `test construction`() {
    mockkConstructor(B::class)
    every { anyConstructed<B>() } returns mockk<B>()

    val a = A()
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not compile. Error: *Missing mocked calls inside every { ... } block: make sure the object inside the block is a mock*

I tried it this way

```
fun `test construction`() {
    mockkConstructor(B::class)
    every { A() } returns mockk<B>()

    val a = A()
}
```

But this way it calls the real constructor of A and also the real constructor of B in the init method of A.

Does anybody know if it's possible to solve it this way or similar?

Comment: What are you testing? If the constructor has no secondary effects, then the test is "weird", if your constructor is using another class, then it has direct acesss to it, (or import), and thus is connected. When mocking, interfaces and boundaries are expected to be set. What behavior are you testing? Also, if A() uses B(), then why are they separated? This could deadlock such as B() uses A(), and tends to aggregate functions.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt to mock `B()` to return a mock of `B` is completely redundant after calling `mockkConstructor(B::class)` which already makes the constructor of `B` return a *prototype mock* denoted by `anyConstructed<B>()`.

This means, you only need `anyConstructed<B>()` to specify the behaviour of calls to that mock, e.g.

```
every { anyConstructed<B>().someFunctionCall() } returns 1
```

See [MockK documentation: Constructor mocks](https://mockk.io/#constructor-mocks) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

So I made a test for these example classes:

```
class A {
    val b: B
    init {
        b = B()
    }
}
class B {
    fun getA(): String {
        return "B"
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
fun test() {
    mockkConstructor(A::class)
    val b = mockk<B>()
    every { anyConstructed<A>().b } returns b
    every { b.getA() } returns "MOCKK"

    val a = A()

    Assert.assertEquals("MOCKK", a.b.getA())
}
```

Comment: Class A is under test. But I don't want to create a real instance of B in my tests. As B is created in the init block of A, I'm searching for a way to mock the instantiation of B since I don't have control over it and I can not inject a mock.

Comment: Ok got it. I'll change my answer

Comment: But the problem is, that this code in the `init` block of A is still called `b = B()`which creates a real object of B which causes the trouble for me

Comment: @axstel, my test was successful. Maybe you're missing something which makes this different in your case?... nevertheless, if so, most likely it means that your code is not quite optimized for testing

Comment: I checked your test. Indeed, it's successful. But my issue is that the constructor/init method of B should never be called. And that's the case in your example. How can I avoid to create a real instance of B? Of course, a mock is returned when I call getA() but a real instance of B is still created in the init method of A

Comment: @axstel, you're right init of B is being called. That is weird, but still understandable... class mocking is not magic right? :) Well, this means that your system (a-b relationship) is not quite testable... You can't really forbid this. Unless make a global static var `isTest` and skip init of B when `isTest = true`

Comment: In case anyone else runs into this problem, I was able to prevent class B from calling its `init` block by making class B a lazy loaded property in class A, and mocking the variable call. `every { a.b } returns mockkedB`